# Why first click not working, but works on second click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have Jquery Code for search suggestions,

HTML Code:

```
                     <div class="search-section">
                        <div class="search-inner">
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="search_input">
                            <input type="hidden" class="redirectUrl">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-redirect">Search</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-section">
                            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
const allConstList = ['John','Micheal','Allen','Jarvis'];

$(document).on('keyup change','.search_input',function(e) {
        const inpVal = e.target.value;
        const $dropdownSection = $(e.target).parent().parent().find('.dropdown-section');
        $dropdownSection.empty();
        $dropdownSection.show();
        for(const constId in allConstList){
            const constName = allConstList[constId];
            if(constName.toLowerCase().includes(inpVal.toLowerCase()))
                $dropdownSection.append(`<li class="dropdown-list-item" data-title="${constName}">${constName}</li>`);
        }
    });
    $('body').click('.dropdown-list-item',function(e) {
            const title = e.target.getAttribute('data-title');
            $(e.target).parent().parent().find('.search_input').val(title);
            $(e.target).parent().parent().find('.dropdown-section').hide();
    });
```

In this I have to click `.dropdown-list-item` twice, on first click nothing happening.

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include all relevant code (HTML). need to see what your `.dropdown-list-item` item looks like and where it's located

Comment: Also I belive the problem is your (keyup change), because when you click an item your change event will trigger and "refesh" the list

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, I have updated Jquery snippet, .dropdown-list-item is actually a list item

Comment: I have figured out actual issue is keyup event in search_input, but without keyup event change event not getting triggered